# How to sort months correctly in chartjs and Laravel eloquent? Order by date ASC + group by date (Month) results in unordered months

Tags: php, laravel, charts, eloquent

I am creating a chart to count how many `checkIR` has been inserted and group them by month. Here is the eloquent code:

```
$data = Report::select('checkIR', 'startDateTime')->orderBy('startDateTime', 'ASC')->get()->groupBy(function($data) {
            return Carbon::parse($data->startDateTime)->format('M');
        });
```

When I change the order to DESC it sorts it correctly but starting from May. However, when sorting ASC, it sorts the months like: `Mar, Feb, Jan, Apr, May`
[image]

The data is being fetched from mySQL as array then json encoded into the chart:

```
$months = [];
$monthsCount = [];

foreach( $data as $month => $values ) {
            $months[] = $month;
            $monthsCount[] = count($values);
        }
```

**Chartjs:**

```
var ydata = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($months) !!}');
var xdata = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($monthsCount) !!}');

     const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
     const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ydata,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Total IRs',
                data: xdata,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
```

Comment: is it true that when you return the ```startDateTime``` only without parsing it into a carbon object like this:```$data = Report::select('checkIR', 'startDateTime')->orderBy('startDateTime', 'ASC')->get()```
it returns correctly ordered ?

Comment: It turned out that it does sort the dates correctly, as Feb and Mar is for the year 2020, then start at Jan 2022